# Example of using [0][width] in format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, format-string

I have the following format string:

```
>>> '{num:+,.4f}'.format(num=-200000)
```

This uses the:

- `[sign]`
- `[grouping_option]`
- `[.precision]`
- `[type]`

Options in the format specifier [defined here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

The format spec is defined as:

```
format_spec     ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#] here ==> [0][width]<== here [grouping_option][.precision][type]
```

What would be an example of the `[0]` and `[width]` options? What are those used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Width` means pad the entire number on the left so that it produces *at least* that many characters, useful when the numbers need to line up. The `0` means pad the width with zeros instead of spaces.

```
>>> '{num:+20,.4f}'.format(num=-200000)
'       -200,000.0000'
>>> '{num:+020,.4f}'.format(num=-200000)
'-00,000,200,000.0000'
```